# SiteLogo Snippet

Tags: custom-masterpage, site-logo

I am using the SiteLogo snippet to refer to my image inside the masterpage/myproject folder, the code is like that:

```
 <!--MS:<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" ID="x9fbc6fd118c9478d8335c24f0632e9fd" LogoImageUrl="images/logo.png" runat="server">-->
```

When referencing that, in the homepage for the site, it's bringing the logo perfectly, but in site settings page, it's broken, it's giving me this:

```
http://mywebapp/sites/mywebsite/sites/mywebsite/_catalogs/masterpage/myproject/images/logo.png
```

The correct url should be:

```
http://mywebapp/sites/mywebsite/_catalogs/masterpage/myproject/images/logo.png
```

why is it broken in the settings page?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can it be that you are using different master pages for "Default master page" and "Custom master Page"?

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for your reply, it's the same master page, I can see my design on both cases, but the logo doesn't appear in site settings, it's broken